# Cannot get insert to work with datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am writing a program in C# using a stored procedure from an Employee class to populate an editable DataGridView.  I can get the grid to populate with the appropriate DataTable, and I can get the Update method to work by using the CellEndEdit event. I see the blank "new row" at the bottom of the grid allowing the user to add a new row.  However, I cannot get the new row to work. I believe it is calling the CellEndEdit once the first cell has been populated, but then it errors out because of the null values in the remaining table fields.
Because I am using methods within the Employee class to perform Insert, Update, Delete, I am not using a TableAdapter.  I believe my steps at this point should be to test to see if this is a new row, if so, I would need to disable the CellEndEdit.

I attempted to use the RowLeave event as follows:

```
 private void dgvEmployee_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvEmployee.Rows[dgvEmployee.CurrentCell.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
        {
            EmployeeDataAccess empData = new EmployeeDataAccess();

            empData.InsertEmployee(dgvEmployee[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   dgvEmployee[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   dgvEmployee[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmployee[4, e.RowIndex].Value));

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

I have tried this block of code in the CellEndEdit to not execute if it is a New Row:

```
 private void dgvEmployee_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvEmployee.Rows[dgvEmployee.CurrentCell.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                dgvEmployee.CellEndEdit -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvEmployee_CellEndEdit);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                EmployeeDataAccess empData = new EmployeeDataAccess();

                empData.UpdateEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmployee[0, e.RowIndex].Value),
                                       dgvEmployee[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                       dgvEmployee[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                       dgvEmployee[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                       Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmployee[4, e.RowIndex].Value));
            }
        }
```

I am not getting an error, but the program will not execute the Insert statement.

Can someone give me a bit of direction as to how to allow a new row to call the insert method?

**UPDATE:**  I did want to mention that I am not using buttons.  When a user edits the data in the DataGridView, I need the data to be updated as they leave the cell. This has been accomplished with the CellEndEdit event calling the Update method.   I am looking for the same result when a user enters data in the New Row. I would like the user to be able to complete entering the data in all columns, then the New Row should be automatically Inserted into my Data Table when the last column has been edited.

Comment: Are you able to successfully run the stored proc within SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. If I remove the CellEndEdit code, and call the Insert method from the RowLeave event, it accepts the inserted row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void dgvEmployee_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_newRow)
        {
            EmployeeDataAccess empData = new EmployeeDataAccess();
            dgvEmployee.EndEdit();

            empData.InsertEmployee(
                                   dgvEmployee[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   dgvEmployee[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   dgvEmployee[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(),
                                   Convert.ToInt32(dgvEmployee[4, e.RowIndex].Value)
                                   );

            _newRow = false;
            dgvEmployeeBindGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }


public void InsertEmployee(string initials, string firstName, string lastName, int active)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.NorthGA_WarpingTest))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "InsertEmployee";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initials", initials);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = active;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }


    @Initials varchar(3),
    @FirstName varchar(25),
    @LastName varchar(25),
    @Active bit

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

INSERT INTO [Employee]
           ( 
             [Initals],
             [FName],
             [LName],
             [Active]         
            )

 VALUES (
          @Initials,
          @FirstName,
          @LastName,
          @Active
        )

END
```

Comment: I solved my problem by entering the dgvEmployee.EndEdit(); above my method call, as well as entering the dgvEmployeeBindGrid(); to refresh the DataGridView with the new row.  It works perfectly, now!

Answer (score 0):

private bool _newRow;

```
    private void dgvEmployee_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_newRow)
        {
            //cancel
        }
        else
        {
            //update
        }
    }

    private void dgvEmployee_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        _newRow = true;
    }

    private void dgvEmployee_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_newRow)
        {
            //insert
            _newRow = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This allows me to update and enter the data into the new row, but it will not update the database.  I have tried the insert method from the SSMS, and it works.  When I enter the new row, I am not getting an error, the program adds an additional row and leaves this one, but is not touching my database.

Comment: My apologies, I had forgotten to assign the RowLeave event. Now, I am receiving an InvalidCastException error stating that "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." I am entering an employees Initials, first name, last name and an active check box. There is an employeeID field that should be automatically added in the database.

Comment: No need to apologies :) Glad to see that you solved your problem.If this approach helped your problem please mark this as answered so that it may help others...

Comment: It isn't solved.  I am now getting Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Did you check your store procedures output parameters? You should return employeeID and bind to your column

Comment: I don't have any output parameters.  Basically, the stored procedure only inserts the New Row into the existing table.  Then, my thought was to rebind the DataSource of the displayed DataGridView.  For some reason, my program errors out when it is trying to accept the DataGridView Cell Values into the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you show me your stored procedure or InsertEmployee method.

Comment: I am having troubles understanding how to put it on here. Can you message me on another app? Wurmwyvern on twitter or yahoo.com

Comment: I cannot figure out how to put my code in this comment.  It tells me I have entered too many characters.  I tried the `` around my code, and it did not work.  Then I indented 4 spaces, no luck.  Next, I tried to indent 8 spaces and all results tell me i have too many characters in my comment :(.. The Insert Employee is above in my original dgvEmployee_RowLeave post.  The SQL basically accepts the four values and inserts them into the table Employee.

Comment: Did you try to update your answer? not in the comment sections

Comment: I have added to your answer.  I hope this is what you needed.